# Instance method not found (return type defaults to 'id') for init

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm creating an `init` method with the following signature:

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary AndLocation:(CLLocation *)location
```

but get this warning message:

```
Instance method '-initWithDictionary:AndLocation:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

However, if I stick a breakpoint in the `init` method I'm definitely hitting it so:

1. why the warning?
2. how do I get rid of it?

Fwiw, I've rebooted xcode, deleted derived data, Build Clean, etc.

This method signature is not in the .h file but I'm pretty sure that `init` methods should not exist there (e.g. [Objective-C: Should init methods be declared in .h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749628/objective-c-should-init-methods-be-declared-in-h)).

Comment: init methods SHOULD exist in header file

Comment: Dude! `init` is not needed to be declared because the superclass(NSObject) declares it. Any method you want to use has to be declared somewhere public. You need to declare it in the .h

Comment: Note that Cocoa style would be to name the method `initWithDictionary:location:`, leaving off the "and", as well as lowercasing the first word of the second (and any subsequent) label; the lowercasing is more important than the "and", though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any method that you intend to use outside of the implementation file must be declared in the header file or you will receive warnings (or errors). This includes `init...` methods.

If you really don't want to have an `init...` method in your header file (though I'm not sure why you wouldn't), you could create a static constructor method mirroring it instead.

```
@interface YourClass : YourSuperclass
+ (instancetype)createWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary location:(CLLocation *)location;
@end
```

Then implement it simply in your implementation file:

```
@implementation YourClass
+ (instancetype)createWitDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary location:(CLLocation *)location {
  return [[self alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary location:location];
  // or for non-ARC:
  // return [[[self alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary location:location] autorelease];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the signature to the .h file.
You are misunderstanding the comment in the link - you don't need to add a specific `- (id) init` method if you are inheriting from `NSObject` because init is already defined.

Add `- (instancetype) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary AndLocation:(CLLocation *)location;` to your header